# Como hacer conexión a base de datos con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estoy aprendiendo `PHP` y en la clase de vídeos que estoy viendo digamos que la forma que esta haciendo la conexión esta desactualizada, pregunte y me dijeron que esa manera la quitaron en `PHP7` pero no me dijeron como hacer la conexión en `PHP7`.

Así que mi consulta es:

> ¿Como se hace la conexion a base de datos en PHP7?

Comment: Busca algo como `PDO` y consultas preparas, con eso haras una conexcion segura y tendras protegidas tus consultas

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Tu pregunta no se encuentra en los tópicos de la página (Lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) .) Lee la documentación de PHP: Puedes elegir entre [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) y [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para hacer conexiones a la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla sería algo así:

Lo primero, crear un archivo de conexión PHP que sería el siguiente:

```
<?php 
function getConn(){
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', "nombre_db");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

Y ya estaría realizada la `conexión` a la `bbdd`.

Después, si quieres desde otra pagina conectarte a tu base de datos, con estas dos líneas estarías conectando.

```
require_once 'conexion.php';

$mysqli = getConn();
```

Comment: Votaste negativa mi pregunta amigo :/

Comment: Intento  votar positivamente porque me sirvió, y no me deja me dice que los miembros con menos de 15 de reputación no se muestra algo así y ahora sale como que vote negativamente :C No se que pasa

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado!!! con eso es suficiente!